# How to rebuild SYSAUX corrupted tablespace?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, corruption, tablespaces

I have database 10g 32-bit windows without backup. I want to migrate full database to 11g, but the `SYSAUX` tablespace is corrupted.

Can I rebuild the `SYSAUX` tablespace?

Comment: It will be very unlikely that you'll be able to recover the database. Does it start up? Can you at least mount it?

Comment: Yes my database in open state and also give error about Hard Drive  I/O device error

Comment: OK that's good, see hot2use's answer

Answer (score 1):

Corruption of the `SYSAUX` tablespaces is apparently a normal thing. It happens every now and then and can be fixed following these steps:

#### Find the corrupt block ([V$DATABASE_BLOCK_CORRUPTION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1074.htm#REFRN30048))

Run the following script to retrieve the blocks that are corrupt:

```
select * from v$database_block_corruption;
```

This will output a list of corrupt blocks. In most cases rebuilding the index where the corrupt block is located will fix the corruption.

#### Rebuild all the indexes ([Script](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sysaux_corruption.htm))

Run the following script to rebuild all the indexes for the SYSAUX tablespace:

```
    set lines 90;
    set heading off;
    set feedback off;

    spool runme.sql

    select
    'alter index '||owner||'.'||index_name||' rebuild online tablespace sysaux;'
    from
    dba_indexes
    where tablespace_name = 'SYSAUX';

    spool off

    spool rebuild.lst
    @runme.sql
    spool off
```

#### Run [DBMS_REPAIR()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/repair.htmdbms_repair)

Have a look at the official documentation for more details (see references)

#### Open up a Service Request

If all else fails, you might want to consider opening up a Service Request with Oracle.

**Reference:**
- [sysaux corruption tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sysaux_corruption.htm) (Burleson Consulting)
- [Using DBMS_REPAIR to Repair Data Block Corruption](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/repair.htmdbms_repair) (Oracle)
- [V$DATABASE_BLOCK_CORRUPTION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1074.htm#REFRN30048) (Oracle)

> **Disclaimer**
>   In no way affiliated with any of the companies.

Comment: I wouldn't assume the corrupt block is in an index...

Comment: True It doesn't have to be, but reading the article seems to imply that it can be common for the indexes to have a corruption in SYSAUX.